# Chow Structural Test in R

Tags: r, regression, structural-change, chow-test

I am sitting on a pile of data concerning wages at a local company and other information, such as the gender, whether the person in question belongs to a minority group etc. What I would like to investigate is whether an additional year of education gives the same relative increase in wages for lower and higher education. For this purpose, I have divided the original data into two subcategories; one group with at most 12 years of education and the other with 13 or more years of education. What I would like to perform is a Chow test of structural change of the form

\begin{equation}
F=\frac{\frac{(RSS-(RSS_{\text{lower}}+RSS_{\text{higher}}))}{2}}{\frac{RSS_{\text{lower}}+RSS_{\text{higher}}}{n-2k}}=\frac{(n-2k)((RSS-(RSS_{\text{lower}}+RSS_{\text{higher}}))}{2(RSS_{\text{lower}}+RSS_{\text{higher}})} \sim F(k,n-2k)
\end{equation}
where $n$ is the total number of observations and $k$ is the number of explanatory variables.

Clearly, I could simply calculate the $RSS:$s directly and then construct $F$ explicitly.

```
 total<-lm(SALARY~EDUC+GENDER+MINORITY)
    lower<-lm(SALARY1~EDUC1+GENDER1+MINORITY1)
    higher<-lm(SALARY2~EDUC2+GENDER2+MINORITY2)
    RSStot<-sum(residuals(total)^2)
    RSSlow<-sum(residuals(lower)^2)
    RSShig<-sum(residuals(higher)^2)
    ((576-6)((RSStot-(RSSlow+RSShig)))/(2(RSSlow+RSShig))
```

> Nevertheless, I am sure there must be a way to do this directly in R. How exactly would that be? I would truly appreciate any enlightenment from any kindhearted spirit. Cheers to all!

Answer (score 1):

Go over my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93529/dummies-instead-of-the-chow-test/93548#93548). You can use `sctest` function in package `strucchange`.