# Test for the significance of the effect of an intervention in a time series

Tags: r, time-series, intervention-analysis, dynamic-regression, piecewise-linear

I am looking for the best approach to test for the significance of the effect of an intervention that occurred at a known time on a time series data.

Using a toy dataset as an example, I have come up with two approaches.

**Data**

```
y <- c(rnorm(10, 10, 0.12), 9.6, 9.4, 9.3, 9.2, 9.15)
x <- seq(1:15)
df <- data.frame(y = y, x = x)

ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 10.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=df$x)
```

[image: Vertical line shows the intervention occurred after 10th time step]

**1. Piecewise regression**

Fitting two linear regression models to subsets of data before and after the intervention.

```
df1 <- subset(df, x <= 10)
m1 <- lm(y ~ x, data = df1) 
summary(m1) #Obviously non-significant

df2 <- subset(df, x > 10)
m2 <- lm(y ~ x, data = df2)
summary(m2) #Obviously significant
```

Using the formula for comparing slopes from this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55501/test-a-significant-difference-between-two-slope-values).

```
b1 <- coef(summary(m1))[2, 1]
b2 <- coef(summary(m2))[2, 1]
SEb1 <- coef(summary(m1))[2, 2]
SEb2 <- coef(summary(m2))[2, 2]

Z <- (b1-b2)/sqrt(SEb1^2+SEb2^2)
```

And calculating the corresponding P-value.

```
2*pnorm(-abs(Z))
[1] 1.395998e-08
```

*(By the way, is there a more elegant function that does the above?)*

This P-value is highly significant and the one to be reported for the effect of an intervention.

The result is shown graphically by plotting two regression lines before and after. *(Since `lm` showed that the slope of relationship at `x=1:10` is not significantly different from 0, the line is at `y=mean(1:10)`)*

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 10.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=df$x) +
  stat_smooth(method="lm", data=df2, se=F, colour="royalblue1", size = 0.75) +
  geom_segment(x = 1, xend = 10, y = mean(df1$y), yend = mean(df1$y),colour="royalblue1", size=0.75)
```

[image: Piecewise regression]

**2. Dynamic regression with ARIMA**

Fitting two ARIMA models, one without and one with a regressor that codes for the intervention.

```
library(forecast)
y <- ts(y)
intervention <- c(rep(0,10), rep(1,5))

a1 <- auto.arima(y)
summary(a1)
```

Summary shows that `auto.arima` chose ARIMA(0,1,0) as the best model.
Hence, fitting ARIMA(0,1,0) with a regressor using the `Arima` function.

```
a2 <- Arima(y, order=c(0,1,0), xreg=intervention)
```

Then using the LRT test to compare the two models to get the P-value associated with the effect of an intervention.

```
library(lmtest)
lrtest(a1, a2)
```

Obviously, the P-value is highly significant.

One advantage of dynamic regression is that it can be used to get forecasts.

```
intf <- c(rep(1,5))
autoplot(forecast(a2, h=5, xreg=intf))
```

[image: Forecasts from ARIMA(0,1,0)]

**Questions**

1. Are both methods adequate and adequately executed?
2. Are there any other methods?
3. Which method would be the preferred one?

Comment: This data can be modeled using transfer function modeling. Auto.arima/R does NOT have this capability,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are referring to is called a test for *structural change/break* or a *changepoint model*.

As you have a known change date, you can simply add an interaction in the model, and use a standard t-test for this coefficient. If you test for more coefficients, use the [Chow test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow_test) formulation (see this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95719/chow-structural-test-in-r) for example). This will work for both a linear regression or an ARIMA. So the choice between these two models should be made based on general considerations, and is not influenced by your desire to do a test.

So you just model:

$y_i = \alpha + \alpha^+ 1(x>10) +\beta x_i + \beta^+x_i1(x>10) + \epsilon_i$

And run a test for the (joint) significance of $\beta^+$ and $\alpha^+$.
Quick example, without the Chow test, just looking at individual coefs:

```
y <- c(rnorm(10, 10, 0.12), 9.6, 9.4, 9.3, 9.2, 9.15)
x <- seq(1:15)
df <- data.frame(y = y, x = x)
df$D <- ifelse(x<10, 0,1)

reg <- lm(y~1+D+ x*(1-D)+x*(D), data=df)
```

Then the `summary` method will show if your coefficients are significant:

```
summary(reg)
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  9.82048    0.08167 120.241  < 2e-16 ***
D            1.62439    0.34875   4.658 0.000696 ***
x            0.03889    0.01451   2.680 0.021417 *  
D:x         -0.19901    0.03054  -6.516 4.33e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

`D` and `D:x` are the $\alpha^+$ and $\beta^+$ coefficients. Hence, you can check three tests:

- $H_0: \alpha^+=0$, i.e. break in intercept. Here, very low p-value for `D`, hence rejectected, so there is break in intercept.
- $H_0: \beta^+=0$, i.e. break in slope. Also very low p-value for `D:x`.
- $H_0: \alpha^+ \beta^+=0$ Null of no break in all coefficient (joint test).

For this, use `linearHypothesis` as below. Also rejected.

```
library(car)
linearHypothesis(reg, c("D=0", "D:x=0"))
```

Finally, plotting is pretty easy:

```
plot(y~x, data=df)
lines(predict(reg))
```

In general, look at the `strucchange` package in R, which is really good, and more general (allows you to search for the date/change value itself). For example:

```
library(strucchange)

breakpoints(y~1+x, data=df, h=0.2, breaks=1)
sctest(Fstats(y~1+x, data=df, from=0.2, to=0.2))
```

The first estimates the break point (10, which corresponds to your 11 I believe), the second tests for constancy.

Comment: In the model summary, which corresponds to the significance of the effect of the intervention, the t-test on the coefficient `D` or the interaction term `D:x` ? If `D:x` , how would you interpret the significance of `D` ? (Both are strongly significant in this example).

Comment: Hi @Mihael, I edited the answer, let me know if you need more clarifications before marking as answered.

Comment: Thank you for an insightful answer! You mentioned that this kind of problem could be tackled either using a linear regression or an ARIMA, depending on general considerations. Could you please elaborate a little on what kind of considerations these would be? In case this is analysed with an ARIMA, would an LRT-test on baseline ARIMA vs. dynamic ARIMA with a regressor be a correct approach?