# Measuring the effect of an outside force on time series with trend and seasonality

Tags: r, time-series, python, change-point, intervention-analysis

Let's say I have a time series that shows daily traffic to my website. My website is getting more popular so there's a trend up, and the traffic is based on day of week so it's cyclical with a period of 7 days.

At a known date, I rolled out a new feature that was supposed to increase traffic to the site. What sort of test do I use to find out if there has been an effect after that point, and what the size of the effect was?

If there were no trend and I was dealing with non time-series data, I could just do a paired t-test comparing specific weekdays from before and after the feature to each other, but since there's a trend up, I get a false positive even if no change has been made. So what's the correct approach here? I found [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246474/test-for-the-significance-of-the-effect-of-an-intervention-in-a-time-series) but am having a hard time understanding the answer, and the series doesn't have the same characteristics as mine (trend, seasonality).

Comment: How about regression to check slopes?

Comment: Wouldn't the seasonality make that not a viable option?

Comment: If you are interested only in the global trend then it does not matter, the seasonal effects should cancel out.